# Route bottle server two subfolders?

Tags: python, routes, bottle

Two subfolders are under same folder called frontend.

One is app, another is dist.

in my main.py, i route like following

```
@bottle.route('/') 
def server_static(filename="index.html"):
  return static_file(filename, root='./frontend/dist/')

@bottle.route('/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
  return static_file(file path, root='./frontend/dist/')
```

Now when user visit the main site url like www.example.com/, they could successfully load everyting from folder dist.

But I wish to add a specific routing for folder app. so that when user visit www.example.com/dev/, everything from folder app will be loaded.

I have tried

```
@bottle.route('/dev') 
def server_static(filename="index.html"):
  return static_file(filename, root='./frontend/app/')

@bottle.route('/dev/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
  return static_file(file path, root='./frontend/app/')
```

But this simply doesn't work. I think it's due to my using of filepath.

Anyone may kindly advise on how to route in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When two routes match, the one declared first is chosen. You need to declare your most specific routes first:

```
@bottle.route('/') 
...

@bottle.route('/dev') 
...
@bottle.route('/dev/<filepath:path>')
...

# because this matches the previous two routes, it must come after them
@bottle.route('/<filepath:path>')
...
```

Comment: strangely i still get error as following "INFO 2014-03-27 13:59:21,853 server.py:593] default: "GET /dev HTTP/1.1" 304 -" even i follow the sequences. Any advice?

Comment: 304 is fine. It means your browser has a copy of the static file already